# Parse not deleting objects Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I was trying to delete objects from Parse Class where requesterUsername is equals to current Username. I have more than 7 rows of data in Parse database but when I execute the method below `objects.size()` returns 0 which was not my expectation and **it does not delete any rows from the database.**

I am clueless here. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
 public void requestGride(View view){

    if(requestActive == false) {
        Log.i("MyApp", "Gride requested");


        ParseObject request = new ParseObject("Requests");
        request.put("requesterUsername", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

        ParseACL parseACL = new ParseACL();
        parseACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
        request.setACL(parseACL);

        request.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                    infoTextView.setText("Finding Gride..");
                    grideX.setText("Cancel GrideX");
                    requestActive = true;

                }
            }
        });
    }else{

        infoTextView.setText("GrideX Cancelled");
        grideX.setText("GrideX");
        requestActive = false;



       ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Requests");

        query.whereEqualTo("requesterUsername",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

                if(e == null){

                    if(objects.size() > 0){

                        for (ParseObject adds : objects){
                            adds.deleteInBackground();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe the getCurrentUser() is null? You should provide some logs or something... also I would not try to delete objects this way, try to use function deleteAllInBackground because it could delete everything in one network request rather than creating seven seperated network requests...

Comment: It didn't help at all. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you please the deleteInBackground function with callback and check if the ParseException is not null?

Comment: ParseException is null

Comment: null is ok, when you create the ACL (above) can you please also call to parseACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);  before settings the ACL?

Comment: Thanks Ran Hassid, it solved my problem....

Comment: Cool :) happy to help